# GDB can detect symbol names of function stubs on the PLT, but LLDB can not

Tags: c, debugging, assembly, gdb, lldb

I am trying to open a C executable in lldb to make myself more comfortable with assembly.

My problem is that when i open the executable with GDB, disassembly output looks like this:

```
call 0x1030 <puts@plt>
```

And that is ok.

But when i use LLDB, output looks like this:

```
call 0x1030 ; stub for __lldb_unnamed_symbol67
```

Why does LLDB not detect the symbol name for a function stub on the PLT, but GDB does?

Comment: What OS?  Both on GNU/Linux?

Comment: Yes, both on Arch Linux

Comment: lldb certainly could, it just doesn't yet.  People have been working on gdb for decades longer than on lldb, so there are lots of corners lldb hasn't gotten to filling in yet.  If this is important to you, please file an ER at the http://bugs.llvm.org site or if it's really important to you, you could try adding this feature to lldb yourself.